# django makemigrations fails after removing a class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I have a model like this:

```
class States(Enum):
    first = 'one'
    second = 'two'

choices = (
    (States.first, 'First'),
    ...
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    state = FSMField(choices=choices)
```

and another model like:

```
class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    new_state = CharField(choices=myapp.choices)
```

For various reasons, I removed the `States` Enum and replaced it with a bunch of constants like:

```
FIRST = 'one'
```

I then migrated my database, and it all went fine.
But when I later run `./manage.py makemigrations`, I get an `AttributeError: module 'myapp.models' has no attribute 'States'.

The traceback ends like this:

```
File "myapp/migrations/0038_xxx.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "myapp/migrations/0038_xxx.py", line 36, in Migration
    ('new_state', models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[(myapp.models.States('one'), 'First'), (myapp.models.States('two'), 'Second')])),
AttributeError: module 'myapp.models' has no attribute 'States'
```

but if I paste the `States` definition back into my `models` file, then `makemigrations` runs fine.

How am I supposed to remove this code if old migrations still require it? I have a bunch of migrations that follow this `0038`, most of which have already been applied to the production database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove refernces to this old enum you can use search and replace to modify `myapp.models.States('one')` with `'one'` in your migrations.

Answer (score -1):

Did you also change your choices tuple to use the new constants like this?

```
choices = (
(FIRST, 'First'),
...
)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that.